# Prevent divs from wrapping, but do not add default scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Alright, so I'm a little puzzled about this: as you can see on the site for [the Polymer Project](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-tabs/demo.html), they have tabs that are horizontally scrollable if there are too many. I'd like to replicate this effect, but I can't figure out how to both prevent the `<div>` elements for tabs from wrapping *as well as* scrolling. Obviously, JS will need to be used here. Unless it's possible to get a custom scrollbar?

How can I do the above? A non-jQuery solution would be **very much** preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to use plain JavaScript or jQuery to compare the calculated width of the inner div to the set width of the outer div. If `#inner` is wider than `#outer`, add a class to one of the divs to change how they're displayed. If not, remove the class.

The markup:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  <div class="scroll-button"></div>
   <!-- your tabs here -->
  <div class="scroll-button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The styling:

```
#outer{
  width:500px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#outer .scroll-buttons{
  display:none;
}
#outer.has-scroll-buttons .scroll-button{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: This didn't answer my question in itself, but it *did* help me find an answer to my question. I'll answer this question myself later. Perhaps my solution isn't the most efficient, though. Accepting yours.

Comment: What part of your question is still unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

Give the divs a fixed height and dynamic length. Where the length property of the div is made by counting the number of columns you want in a div.

Why the aversion to jquery?

Comment: The reason I'd rather not use jQuery is because it's a pretty big library that I'm not going to use in this project, for the most part.